# UIView center position during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uiviewpropertyanimator

I would like to determine, what is the center position of a UIVIew (the middle point of the view) during an animation. An animation with UIViewPropertyAnimator like this:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .easeInOut)
 
var circle : UIView!
circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
self.view.addSubview(circle)

animator.addAnimations {
    circle.center = CGPoint(x: 100,y: 100)
    //or any other point
}
animator.startAnimation()
```

If I print the circle.center property during the animation then I got just the destination position of the animation not the real position.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true, block: {
[weak self] (Timer) -> Void in
if let circleCenterPosition = self?.circle.center
{
    print(circleCenterPosition)
}
})
```

After this print I saw this on the console:

> (100.0, 100.0)
>
> (100.0, 100.0)
>
> ...

How can I print the real position during the animation?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to add the circle to the center of your view, you can do this
`circle.center = self.view.center`

Comment: I would like to know what is the exact position (CGPoint) of my circle during the animation. If I print the circle.center postion to the console, it will show just the start (0.0) and the end position (100,100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a possible answer.

[CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer) has a presentation() function

> func presentation()
>   Returns a copy of the presentation layer object that represents the state of the layer as it currently appears onscreen.

the presentation layer has a frame property what is a CGRect and from here easy the calculate the midpoint.

Demo

[image]

Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var circle : UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .easeInOut)
        circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(circle)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true)
        {
            [weak self] (myTimer) -> Void in
            if let movingBlueDotFrame = self?.circle.layer.presentation()?.frame
            {
                let blueDotOriginPoint = movingBlueDotFrame.origin
                let blueDotMiddlePoint = CGPoint(x: blueDotOriginPoint.x + movingBlueDotFrame.width/2, y: blueDotOriginPoint.y + movingBlueDotFrame.height/2)
                print(blueDotMiddlePoint)
                if blueDotMiddlePoint == CGPoint(x:100,y:100){
                    print("Yeeaahh")
                    myTimer.invalidate()
                }
            }
       }
        animator.addAnimations {
            self.circle.center = CGPoint(x: 100,y: 100)
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

The idea came from here [UIView animation determine center during animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545545/uiview-animation-determine-center-during-animation?rq=1)

If you have some simpler or nicer solution, please add below. Thanks!